# Cocoapods - I am not able to install cocoapods on my mac. I am following the step from cocoapods.org to install cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Why am I facing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL certs in some older Ruby installs have expired.

Update your `ruby` install using `homebrew` then try again.

If you dont have `homebrew` go to [the homebrew site](https://brew.sh) to get install instructions.

Install ruby once that is done

`brew install ruby`

As of 20/08/18 the current version is `2.5.1`

Once you have done that try to reinstall cocoapods with whatever instruction you got from cocoapods or since you now have homebrew try:

`brew install cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks Warren for the answer. But I am still confused. Can you please tell me the steps to follow.

Comment: Thank you so much Warren for providing the steps to follow. I have followed your steps and your solution worked for me. Thanks once again.